# How to provide multiple inputs for a manually triggered (workflow_dispatch) workflow in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a requirement to enter multiple inputs using workflow_dispatch and use matrix to play with them.

**Fox Example:**

I have 10 repositories. When user runs a workflow manually, he/she will need to provide 5/6 repositories as input at a time. I can see workflow_dispatch option, currently supports only string as an input. Is there anyway to deal with this situation using github actions?

Answer (score 1):

So [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) events actually support 3 input types; `choice`, `environment`, `boolean`.

I don't think you'll be able to pass inputs for matrix tasks that expect a list of values though (you can definitely do it for [single values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781005/combine-dynamic-github-workflow-matrix-with-input-values-and-predefined-values)

If there are only several inputs you might be able to use multiple `booleans` and conditionally run jobs or steps. Not as clean clean but will do the job.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repo_1:
        type: boolean
        default: false
        description: Use Repo 1?
      repo_2:
        type: boolean
        default: false
        description: Use Repo 2?
jobs:
  repo-1-job:
    name: Repo 1 Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.inputs.repo_1 == 'true'
    steps:
      - run: echo "some repo 1 job"
  
  repo-2-job:
    name: Repo 2 Job
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.inputs.repo_2 == 'true'
    steps:
      - run: echo "some repo 2 job"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the idea of the [example from the `fromJSON` documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-returning-a-json-object) that sets a JSON matrix in one job, and passes it to the next job using an output.

The first job collects the `true` and `false` values from the inputs and creates a JSON object with key-value pairs where key is the repo and value is the boolean value. `jq` removes the elements with `false` and creates an JSON array of the remaining keys. This is put into the `outputs.repos` variable for the next job.

```
name: repos
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repo_1:
        type: boolean
        default: false
        description: Use Repo 1?
      repo_2:
        type: boolean
        default: false
        description: Use Repo 2?
      repo_3:
        type: boolean
        default: false
        description: Use Repo 3?
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      repos: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.repos }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: >
          echo '{
            "repo_1": ${{ github.event.inputs.repo_1 }},
            "repo_2": ${{ github.event.inputs.repo_2 }},
            "repo_3": ${{ github.event.inputs.repo_3 }}
          }' 
          | echo "repos=$( jq -c 'map_values(. // empty) | keys' )"
          >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT      
  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        repo: ${{ fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.repos) }}
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.repo }}
```