# Github Actions workflow with input type object not running

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

I have this (simplified) workflow:

```
name: runs_on_advanced2

on:
#  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      matrix-ubuntu:
        description: matrix-ubuntu
        type: object
        default:
          runs_on:
            - ubuntu-20.04
            - ubuntu-22.04

jobs:
  matrix_prep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "matrix is ${{ inputs.matrix-ubuntu }}"
```

When I try to trigger it, I get a UI just the way I would like it. But once I press [run workflow], it reports back having a problem with 'on'. I cannot workout why. What am I doing wrong? The github docs don't give me enough detail of how to use 'type: object'.

Comment: [`object` is not supported.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatchinputsinput_idtype) You may use `string` and pass the values as JSON and then expand those for `matrix`.

Comment: Ok. What is this talking about then? Is that deprecated? Still needs to be implemented or ...? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context

Comment: It's talking about the `inputs` itself which is a JSON object.

Comment: Sure thing. Here's an example with JSON as string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781005/combine-dynamic-github-workflow-matrix-with-input-values-and-predefined-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, `type: object` is [not supported](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context) for `inputs`.

Alternatively, you may opt for `type: string` for pass in JSON and utilize it later with [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function.

For your specific use case, you may also opt for `type: choice` and provide all the supported combinations as `options` and later manipulate the selected one with [functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions) to populate the `matrix`.