# Extract matrix step output for each element in a GitHub reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions, cicd, github-actions-reusable-workflows

I am facing an issue with getting the matrix build output for each step and running something after that, using a GitHub reusable workflow.

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        jdk: [8, 11, 14, . . .] # User provides this value as input
    runs-on: [self-hosted]

  steps:
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build
      uses: abc_workflow@v1
      with:
        java-version: ${{ matrix.jdk }}
```

Now, I want to extract the build status for all matrix build elements separately and run some checks after that. I have already tried steps.XXX.outcome/steps.XXX.output, but no luck :(

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine dynamic Github Workflow matrix with input values and predefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781005/combine-dynamic-github-workflow-matrix-with-input-values-and-predefined-values)

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. But I am able to handle dynamic input values case, but not able to get the individual matrix output. Sorry for creating the confusion, if any!!